# MS Access unable to locate my excel range when importing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code that works on one spreadsheet, but not another. I am just trying to automate the transfer of an excel data range to an access table, like so

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "UsysFastTrack", strFilePath, False, strRange
```

`strFilePath` and `strRange` are just strings that contain the full file path (including the worksheet name and extension) and the name of an excel range in the worksheet, respectively. This line causes an error

`The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ...`

This error appears a lot online and somewhere I saw the advice to try the import wizard to see what I get and lo and behold, right as I hit the last `Next`

[image]

This is the exact same error and it stops me dead in my tracks. What's funny is that you can see the range exists in the spreadsheet before your very eyes.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the names of your named ranges are not valid, they are similar to regular ranges. Try to change names

Comment: What makes a range name valid?

Comment: Formally your names are valid - they start from letter, do not have special characters, but probably Access driver has issue with named range and range recognition. Try to rename your range to something like "range432432", it should work. At least when I tried, it worked, but names like "f76465" didn't work

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. I'm guessing the range name looks too much like a cell reference, even though the number behind the F is greater than the maximum row number in excel. Interestingly enough, excel allows for ranges to be named like this, but apparently access chokes on it when trying to locate the range. Thanks again.